# Customized email twig templates

Tags: theming, emails, 9

Can anyone tell me if there is a mechanism for creating user registration acceptance / rejection emails from different template files for the default email system ?

In *admin/config/people/accounts*, the **account activation** section seems the correct area for crafting the registration acceptance email. BUT, I don't think anyother section is right for te registration rejection email.

So, I tried to find a means of using twig templates for a various scenarios I am trying to fufil without success. Webforms seems to have this functionality but I need it for the default drupal email system.

Answer (score 1):

You want the Easy Email module: https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_email

It is definitely the best mail solution I've found in all my years of Drupal, allowing for the creation of an on-site editing experience for HTML emails, that can be themed with TWIG templates.